# Null Pointer Exception con JDBC

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

Básicamente quiero conectar mi clase con un **squema** de **MYSQL**. Tengo el servidor levantado pero me tira `NullPointerException`, no se que pasa. Debe ser algún problema de versiones? Estoy usando **MYSQL 8**.

Mi clase conexión:

```
public class Conexion {

    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/control_clientes?useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC";
    private static final String userName = "root";
    private static final String pass = "admin"; 

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, pass);
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(PreparedStatement p) {
        try {
            p.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection conn) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

y mi clase `ClienteDaoJDBC` (Que es donde llamo a la conexión)

```
public class ClienteDaoJDBC {

    ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    private final String SQL_SELECT = "SELECT idcliente, nombre, apellido, email, telefono, saldo FROM cliente";

    public ArrayList<Cliente> conseguirlistadoClientes() {

        PreparedStatement p = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = Conexion.getConnection();
            p = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT);
            rs = p.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Cliente c = new Cliente(
                        rs.getInt("idcliente"), rs.getString("nombre"), rs.getString("apellido"), rs.getString("email"), rs.getString("telefono"), rs.getDouble("saldo"));
                clientes.add(c);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        } finally {
            Conexion.close(conn);
            Conexion.close(rs);
            Conexion.close(p);
        }
        return clientes;
    }
```

ENTIENDO QUE NO SE ME ESTE CONECTANDO A LA BASE. NECESITO SABER POR QUE ME LO TRAE COMO `NULL` A LA CONEXIÓN.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Answer (score 3):

Antes de `DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, pass);` Te falta registrar el driver de `MySQL`

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

También posiblemente te falte el [jar de mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html) en tu proyecto.

Comment: Gracias. Funciono

Comment: @abrahamhs creo que te refieres a que acepte pero la *respuesta* que mas le ayudó ;)

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta que mas te ayudo haciendo click en la palomita

Answer (score 0):

Para poder trabajar con MySQL en Java, primero se debe de añadir al proyecto la librería de  `MySQL JDBC Driver`

---

A continuación se debe de crear en la clase conexión una nueva instancia de la clase que trae la librería anteriormente mencionada:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Lo anterior crea una nueva instancia de la clase `Driver` que posee la librería de **MySQL**  sin parámetros, esto permite poder comunicarse con la base de datos.

Una vez inicializada e instanciada, ya se puede crear la conexión con la base de datos, otorgando la url de la misma, el nombre de usuario y la pass del mismo.

```
DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, pass);
```